# Как "поди (уж) (уже)" выделять запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

Нашел такие примеры без запятых:

1. Поди много денег у него?
2. Он поди уж уехал?

Тогда получается :

Ты поди уж припрятал себе заначку где-нибудь?

Ты поди уже припрятал себе заначку где нибудь? (тоже без запятых?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Везде нужны запятые, так как это вводные слова со значением "должно быть, наверное".

Поди, много денег у него? Он, поди уж, уехал? Ты, поди уж, припрятал себе заначку где-нибудь? Ты, поди, уже припрятал себе заначку где нибудь? (тоже без запятых?)

Также: Там, поди-ка, пятеро парнишек остались.

Но:

Русский характер! Поди-ка опиши его…  Здесь "поди" имеет значение "попробуй".

Поди сюда, у нас такой дорогой гость! ("Поди" в значении "подойди").